# onStart method is being called in a bound service without any method call

Tags: java, android

I have been going through the following [google tutorial](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html), and just had a few questions:

1. i pasted the code and ran it, and i noticed that the onStart() method gets executed. However I do not see any method call for this, how does this method get executed ?
2. can you give an practical example of how a bound service would be ideal ?

Comment: The framework calls onStart when the service is started.  Think of it as like the main() for your service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- That is because onStart() is called by an event, specifically, it is called when the activity becomes visible to the user.

[Here's a nice explanation of the lifecycle of Android activities](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_acitivities.htm):

[image: Android Activity Licecycle]

[diagram source](http://web.archive.org/web/20140218132043/http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/starting.html)

- Your question about [bound services](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/bound-services.html) has already been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14985077/why-would-i-use-a-bound-service) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272217/service-or-bound-service).

Comment: there are different kinds of services -  local services, Aidl , what makes bound services different from them, what would be a practical example that would make them better ?